# How can I disable GPIO warnings?

Tags: raspbian, python, rpi.gpio

I get the following warning: [image: Warning]     Python says to add this command `GPIO.setwarnings(False)`. Where do I put this command, in the file or in some system file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this command before the first call to `GPIO.setup()` in your .py file, as it suppresses warnings in that call.

Answer (score 1):

In any script of python if you are using GPIOs than, at the end means after using it you need to enter the line of `GPIO.cleanup()`. It will be useful for that warnings.